# Migration file with specific version - rails 4

Tags: database, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4, migration

Can i make a migration file with older version to run it before other migrations that existing ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply,

you can rename the file to change the creation date

like from " 20141006123502_ " to " 20140930125520_ "